# How to redirect to another site using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to the Flask and can't fix an issue.
How to redirect to another site?

```
        <h3>Courses</h3>
        {% for c in course %}
          <li>{{ c.name}}</li>
          <li><a href="{{ c.link }}">{{ c.link }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}

c.link - is a text(e.g. https://stackoverflow.com)
```

Can you please explain how to do it right?

Comment: What happens exactly in the code you posted? Does it create a link? If so, when you click on it doesn't it change page?

Comment: what is the error